# Highcharts area graph animation on setData

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

I have a HighCharts.js graph where when clicking a button, setData is called that adds another data point.

I was hoping to change that animation that brings it from 0 to the current next data point, to instead just animate smoothly from left to right as if it is just filling/expanding. Exact animation is shown when it loads.

I have setData simply as follows where the animation attribute is set to true.

```
series.setData(data, true, true);
```

I created this http://jsfiddle.net/44ejxsaa/1/ to create a simple example of the animation I am getting. Please click the button a few times to see.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click. Maybe you need to update the fiddle?

Comment: Ok try http://jsfiddle.net/44ejxsaa/1/, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the 0 entries from the array, as they are causing the chart to connect down to the axis from the last point:

```
data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0];
```

Then set a default `minRange` and `min` so you still see the axis as far as 12 on initialisation:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px'
        }
    },
    min: 0,
    minRange: 12,
},
```

Then use `addPoint` instead of `setData` to get the default animation for adding a point. It's not quite the same as what you see on load though - the point appears immediately.

```
series.addPoint({x : arrayLocation, y: increasingValue});
```

I also initialised `arrayLocation` to 5 to get it to work (otherwise it was generating two points at `x=5`.

```
var arrayLocation = 5;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/odrjvb8w/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason why the animation object does absolutely nothing in setData even though it's in their documentation as a parameter?

Comment: In the [docs for setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) it says "Note that this method throws away all points and creates new ones" so I guess it can't animate the new point because it's treating it as a whole new series not just a new point. So why does it animate in your first version - from the same doc, "When the updated data is the same length as the existing data, points will be updated instead of replace. "